# Post JSON data via ajax, while received nothing in view.py

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, django

I am so confused when I tried to POST JSON data via AJAX and receive it by a function in view.py (part of django framework).

Below is my client code using ajax to send data:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myEvent = {
        user_token: { 
            userid: 1    
        }, 
        title: "test title", 
        privilege: "public"
    };
    console.log($.toJSON(myEvent))

    $.ajax({
        url: '/gallery/new_report/',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: $.toJSON(myEvent),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function(ts) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then the function in views.py:

```
def new_report(request):
    #return HttpResponse(request.body)
    parameters = json.loads(request.body)
    ...
```

the code above do not works but throw a exception says:

> No JSON object could be decoded

But if I uncomment the commented line in this function, the correct JSON string is returned by the HttpResponse.

What should I do to get the correct JSON data via ajax in this situation?

Comment: `toJSON()` isn't a jQuery function...Are you using a jQuery plugin?

Comment: You don't need to use the `$.toJSON` plugin here - you can provide your object directly to the `data` parameter of the AJAX request.

Comment: I would assign the data to a key: `data: {'values': theData}` and then pull the value from `request.POST.get('values')`

Comment: .toJSON() is not a valid jQuery function(unless you are using some plugin). You are most probably getting an error in javascript and are unable to proceed. Try posting it as 

JSON.stringify(myEvent, null, 2);

Comment: @ShobitSharma I tried to use JSON.stringify as you said just now, but failed as before.

Answer (score 0):

I have just put together what others have already said in the comments.

I haven't tested the code, but it should somewhat work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myEvent = {
    user_token: { 
        userid: 1    
    }, 
    title: "test title", 
    privilege: "public"
};
console.log(myEvent)

$.ajax({
    url: '/gallery/new_report/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {'eventValues': myEvent},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function(ts) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

and python view

```
def new_report(request):

    values = request.POST.get('eventValues')
    #assert False, values
    parameters = json.loads(values)
    ...
```

Comment: I agree this is a good way for solving the problem, but what really confused me is why the original code do not works. Thanks anyway !

Comment: the problem lies here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body The raw HTTP request body as a byte string. For processing conventional form data, use HttpRequest.POST

Answer (score 0):

Because body is sent as a byte string so

```
def new_report(request):
    #return HttpResponse(request.body)
    parameters = json.loads(request.body.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
    ...
```

is probably what you're looking for